# Does SharePoint 2013 file search favour Microsoft documents over PDFs?

Tags: search, sharepoint

I have a Content Source which crawls a network folder containing Word, PowerPoint and PDF documents. I have in addition a Result Source based directly on this content source and a Search Results web part which uses the Result Source as its query. If I search for “Digital Cameras” the first result is a PowerPoint document entitled “Digital Cameras: Thriving Amidst a Declining Market.” However, there is a PDF file also in the directory with the exact same title, but this file does not appear unless I filter by PDF Result Type, at which point it appears at the top of the list. In fact, with Result Type set to All, I cannot see the PDF version of the file even if I click through all the pages of the initial search.

I thought it might be considered a duplicate but I have “Show View Duplicates” checked and “Trim Duplicates” set to false. The pop-out next to the initial search item does not show a duplicate.

How do I get the PDF document to appear in the basic search next to the PowerPoint document with the same title?

Comment: This seems to be better suited over at: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

In your search center (which may or may not be your main site or a specific subsite designated through Central Admin), go to site settings and then Search Result Types and there should be a list of the result types included in your default search.

Provided you are crawling the PDFs in your search crawl (Central Admin > go to your Search Service > Crawling > File Types) , and they have content that can be indexed (namely text in the documents and title and not just images inside the PDF), you should be seeing it then.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have added the question at the other place:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137512/does-sharepoint-2013-file-search-favour-microsoft-documents-over-pdfs

Graham, thanks I checked the result types and the crawling types and all looks OK. Plus, if the item was not being crawled it would not show up in the search even with the filtering.